# How to declare a Variable to use for all function in Laravel 6 and above laravel version?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7

I want to declare a variable $id

This id will be the Auth::id()

Now what will be the apporach?

Code:

```
private static $id;

public function __construct()
{
   $this->id = Auth::id();
}
```

But this id is not accessible from function Query.

```
Invoice::where([
     ['userID', '=', $id],
     ['created_at', '=', $todayDate]
])->get();
```

Giving error in this line: ['userID', '=', $id],

Undefined Variable $id.

Thanks for Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function __construct(){
    self::$id = Auth::id();
}
```

NOTE: If there is any `static` member function or variable in the class, we cannot refer it using the `$this`.

Just use like below

```
Invoice::where([
   ['userID'=>self::id],
   ['created_at'=>$todayDate]
])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct()
{
   self::$id = Auth::id();
}
```

```
Invoice::where([
     ['userID', '=', self::$id],
     ['created_at', '=', $todayDate]
])->get();
```

Use self keyword, this will helps